# How do I initiate the function on button click?

Tags: javascript

Following code starts a chess game in initial position integrating chess.js library.

```js
var board = null
var game = new Chess()
var $status = $('#status')
var $fen = $('#fen')
var $pgn = $('#pgn')

function onDragStart (source, piece, position, orientation) {
  // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
  if (game.game_over()) return false

  // only pick up pieces for the side to move
  if ((game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
      (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
    return false
  }
}

function onDrop (source, target) {
  // see if the move is legal
  var move = game.move({
    from: source,
    to: target,
    promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
  })

  // illegal move
  if (move === null) return 'snapback'

  updateStatus()
}

// update the board position after the piece snap
// for castling, en passant, pawn promotion
function onSnapEnd () {
  board.position(game.fen())
}

function updateStatus () {
  var status = ''

  var moveColor = 'White'
  if (game.turn() === 'b') {
    moveColor = 'Black'
  }

  // checkmate?
  if (game.in_checkmate()) {
    status = 'Game over, ' + moveColor + ' is in checkmate.'
  }

  // draw?
  else if (game.in_draw()) {
    status = 'Game over, drawn position'
  }

  // game still on
  else {
    status = moveColor + ' to move'

    // check?
    if (game.in_check()) {
      status += ', ' + moveColor + ' is in check'
    }
  }

  $status.html(status)
  $fen.html(game.fen())
  $pgn.html(game.pgn())
}

var config = {
  draggable: true,
  position: 'start',
  onDragStart: onDragStart,
  onDrop: onDrop,
  onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
}
board = Chessboard('board2', config)

updateStatus()
```

After checkmate though there is no option to clear the board. Is there a way to integrate the following code so I can only start the game or the clear the board if the respective button is clicked? The start button places the pieces in their default position on a clear board using only the draggable function set to true within Chessboard.

```js
$('#startBtn').on('click', board2.start)
$('#clearBtn').on('click', board2.clear)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added the code for the buttons at the bottom of your code. This code attaches event handlers to the start and clear buttons, so it could be placed anywhere outside of a function. Here's some code to display the two buttons below the board. I also added some code to run the code inside the code snippet.

```js
var board = null
var game = new Chess()
var $status = $('#status')
var $fen = $('#fen')
var $pgn = $('#pgn')

function onDragStart (source, piece, position, orientation) {
  // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
  if (game.game_over()) return false

  // only pick up pieces for the side to move
  if ((game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
      (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
    return false
  }
}

function onDrop (source, target) {
  // see if the move is legal
  var move = game.move({
    from: source,
    to: target,
    promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
  })

  // illegal move
  if (move === null) return 'snapback'

  updateStatus()
}

// update the board position after the piece snap
// for castling, en passant, pawn promotion
function onSnapEnd () {
  board.position(game.fen())
}

function updateStatus () {
  var status = ''

  var moveColor = 'White'
  if (game.turn() === 'b') {
    moveColor = 'Black'
  }

  // checkmate?
  if (game.in_checkmate()) {
    status = 'Game over, ' + moveColor + ' is in checkmate.'
  }

  // draw?
  else if (game.in_draw()) {
    status = 'Game over, drawn position'
  }

  // game still on
  else {
    status = moveColor + ' to move'

    // check?
    if (game.in_check()) {
      status += ', ' + moveColor + ' is in check'
    }
  }

  $status.html(status)
  $fen.html(game.fen())
  $pgn.html(game.pgn())
}

pieceTemplates = ({wiki:'https://chessboardjs.com/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png',
             alpha:'https://chessboardjs.com/img/chesspieces/alpha/{piece}.png'})
             
var config = {
  draggable: true,
  pieceTheme:pieceTemplates.wiki,
  position: 'start',
  onDragStart: onDragStart,
  onDrop: onDrop,
  onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
}

board = Chessboard('board', config)
updateStatus()

$('#startBtn').on('click', function () {
  game.reset()
  board.start()
})
$('#clearBtn').on('click', function () {
  game.reset()
  board.clear()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-q94+BZtLrkL1/ohfjR8c6L+A6qzNH9R2hBLwyoAfu3i/WCvQjzL2RQJ3uNHDISdU"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
      
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ZvpUoO/+PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn/6Z/hRTt8+pR6L4N2"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-8Vi8VHwn3vjQ9eUHUxex3JSN/NFqUg3QbPyX8kWyb93+8AC/pPWTzj+nHtbC5bxD"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chess.js@0.12.1/chess.js"></script>

<div id="board" style="width:400px;"></div>

<button id="startBtn">Start Position</button>
<button id="clearBtn">Clear Board</button>
```

Comment: Your code worked. However on clear and then start position the game function seems to be stuck in its previous state. I added this at the end of the code and it seemed to work:$rstrt.on('click', function () {
  board.start(false)
  game=new Chess()
  updateStatus ()
})

Comment: @PratikBhetwal Good catch! Chess.js also has a reset method. I added this method in my snippet to the clear button handler to reset the state of the game on click.